# Polling the database in a background worker thread - .NET

Tags: .net, database, polling

I am new to .NET ... I am trying to create a background worker thread that can poll the database every 20s to find out whether the data in the database has changed or not.

What are the steps required to do this? Is this a good approach or should i use something else?

Any tutorial/example will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polling a database can be a large performance issue.  If you have control over the service that updates the database, I would suggest issuing an event from that service to any client/service that might be interested in knowing the db has changes for a specific record.

Otherwise, you can look into using a background thread.  To do that, simply create a thread using [System.Threading.Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx).  If you are connecting to a MS SQL Server database, you can use [System.Data.SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx) classes.